# possible to go through all the controls in a form to check if they have been filled or not on submitting the form to sharepoint?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have built a form library in sharepoint, which will contain an info path form inside it.

I wonder if it is possible in any way to iterate through all the controls inside an info path without the need of external c# code, when a specific button has been clicked. I.e. only using info path rules engine. I need to do the following because i want to create a bitmask representation of the form. such that it would be possible to see and check which fields have been filled and which others are yet to be filled for a specific instance of the form

Comment: Use InfoPath rules to validate the form. Aren't they enough to achieve your goal?

Comment: to use validation, i would need to put validation on each and every field that is contained in the info path form, which is not that feasible.

Comment: well, if you need a no-code solution, I don't think you have other options...